# simplify complex roots

Tags: c

i have made a program to compute roots of quauation but it does not simplify the roots.can anyone help me to simplify them

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
void main(void)
{
    int a,b,c;
    float d,d2;
    printf(" Enter a,b and c:");
    scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c);
    d=b*b-4*a*c;

    if(d<0)
    {
        printf("(%d+i%d)/%d\n",-b,sqrt(-d),2*a) ;
        printf("(%d-i%d)/%d\n",-b,sqrt(-d),2*a);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("(%d+%d)/%d\n",-b,sqrt(d),2*a);
        printf("(%d-%d)/%d\n",-b,sqrt(d),2*a);
    }

getch();
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that the sqrt function in math.h can accept negative arguments, and return imaginary roots? That seems unlikely.

Comment: For which values of a,b,c you get the domain error?  I don't see how this can handle complex values.  sqrt can only work on positive values.  Don't expect sqrt to return a complex value (like sqrt(-1)=i).  In C, there is no such concept as complex values, but you could write a complex value class in C++ if you want (but then you have to implement the square root function yourself).

Comment: `complex` data type was introduced in C99.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't compute the square root of a negative number. `d` is negative and you're trying to find its square root. The whole point of complex solutions and the imaginary unit `i` is to write `-1` as `i^2`, and then when `d < 0` you have:

```
sqrt(d) = sqrt(i^2 * (-d)) = i*sqrt(-d)
```

So change to this:

```
if(d<0)
{
    printf("(%d+i%lf)/%d",-b,sqrt(-d),2*a);
    printf("(%d-i%lf)/%d",-b,sqrt(-d),2*a);
}
```

I don't know why you had parantheses around your `printf` arguments, I removed those.

The second `%d` should also be changed to `%lf` since `sqrt` returns a double.

Comment: I like to add, that `sqrt` returns a double and not an integer, so the `%d` should also be changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compute square roots tof negative numbers, find a C99 compiler (basically, anything besides MSVC will do), include `<complex.h>` header, use `complex` data type and `csqrt` function.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex.h